# How to trace Cloudformation events from a Jenkins Job after create/update stack initiated without using Jenkins cloudformation plugin?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

How to trace Cloudformation events from a Jenkins Job after create/update stack initiated without using Jenkins-cloudformation plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Question is not super clear, however you should be able to see the Cloudformation events directly from the Cloudformation console.